# python kernel died on loading keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I execute the following line:

```
 model = vgg16.VGG16(input_tensor=input_img, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

I got this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:The following Variables were used in a Lambda layer's call (tf.concat), but are not present in its tracked objects:   <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 474, 712, 3) dtype=float32>
  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 474, 712, 3) dtype=float32>. This is a strong indication that the Lambda layer should be rewritten as a subclassed Layer.
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Comment: How are you actually importing the vgg16 pretrained model? Please share minimal reproducible code to understand the issue. Also let us know the tensorflow version and python version you are using in jupyter notebook.